# How to sort a very large array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort, large-data

I want to sort on the order of four million `long long`s in C. Normally I would just `malloc()` a buffer to use as an array and call `qsort()` but four million * 8 bytes is one huge chunk of contiguous memory.

What's the easiest way to do this? I rate ease over pure speed for this. I'd prefer not to use any libraries and the result will need to run on a modest netbook under both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Where are the values coming from, and going to? Do you have them all in memory to begin with?

Comment: Where are they currently stored, on disk? I assume you are not running a 64bit system?

Comment: 4 million times 8 is ~32 megabytes. It doesn't need to be contiguous either -- you just need contiguous address space for the mapped addresses of a lot of 4K blocks. IOW, malloc/qsort should be fine.

Comment: 32MB? That's not a huge chunk. That's a tiny chunk.

Comment: 4 million * 8 bytes = 32MB. This is not too much for `malloc()`.

Comment: @Yann Ramin. They are stored on disk in a raw file. I wouldn't mind a disk-based qsort but that seems harder to implement than disk-based bsearch which I have done before.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: I thought the C `qsort()` function only worked with a contiguous array.

Comment: @hippietrail: The array will appear contiguous to your code, but that's only an illusion created by the memory management hardware. In reality, it's allocated as smaller (4k, or on some hardware, 8K) blocks. Bottom line: unless you're on a system with *really* constrained memory, it won't be a problem.

Comment: "640K ought to be enough for anybody."

Comment: I once sorted 4 *billion* long longs.  Now *that* took alternative mechanisms.  But in the end I still used `qsort()` on batches of 19 million entries at a time...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just allocate a buffer and call `qsort`. 32MB isn't so very big these days even on a modest netbook.

If you really must split it up: sort smaller chunks, write them to files, and merge them (a merge takes a single linear pass over each of the things being merged). But, really, don't. Just sort it.

(There's a good discussion of the sort-and-merge approach in volume 2 of Knuth, where it's called "external sorting". When Knuth was writing that, the external data would have been on magnetic tape, but the principles aren't very different with discs: you still want your I/O to be as sequential as possible. The tradeoffs are a bit different with SSDs.)

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that if the data is already raw binary on disk, you could `mmap` (or equivalent) instead of loading and writing it back. But if you care about the safety of your data in the event of a system failure, this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: `qsort()` did work fine of course - I don't know what I was worried about. I probably wasn't aware just how much the memory management provided since I moved from C to scripting languages when a couple of megabytes was lots of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

32 MB?  thats not too big....   quicksort should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to prevent having the data unordered if possible. Like it has been mentioned, you'd be better of reading the data from disk (or network or whatever the source) directly into a selforganizing container (a tree, perhaps `std::set` will do).

That way, you'll never have to sort through the lot, or have to worry about memory management. If you know the required capacity of the container, you might squeeze out additional performance by using `std::vector(initialcapacity)` or call `vector::reserve` up front.

You'd then best be advised to use `std::make_heap` to *heapify* any existing elements, and then add element by element using `push_heap` (see also `pop_heap`). This essentially is the same paradigm as the self-ordering set but

- duplicates are ok
- the storage is 'optimized' as a flat array (which is perfect for e.g. *shared memory maps* or *memory mapped files*)

(Oh, minor detail, note that `sort_heap` on the heap takes at most N log N comparisons, where N is the number of elements)

Let me know if you think this is an interesting approach. I'd really need a bit more info on the use case

Comment: Bloddy ... :) I am blind today. Okay, there must be equivalent approaches in C; I hope this still has some value