# Array sorting in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm not C expert and I've read through the forum, but I still need some advice regarding a sorting problem on C.

I have 4 dynamic arrays of doubles in C. All of them are the same size, and lets say n. What I want to do is to sort all of them using one of the arrays as first order and a second array as my second order. So if the arrays are *x, *y, *w and *z. I want to sort them according to the values of *x, then *y.

I must do this efficiently because the arrays are quite large.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787996/c-library-function-to-do-sort

Comment: The question is how to sort array? Or you know how to sort one array?

Comment: Here: [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/qsort.html). Try something, and if you have a problem then, then we'll talk. About sorting large arrays, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588041/how-to-sort-a-very-large-array-in-c

Comment: @Andrey: There isn't a question as far as I can tell.

Comment: @netcoder I am trying to figure is there actual question that is implied or another "do this for me".

Comment: Thanks for the quick aswers, I mean all of them let me try to be a little more specific. I have 4 different arrays. Two of them contain corrdinates, that is x- coordinate, and y- coordinate. The other two are values for this coordinates. I'm aware that this is not the best approach to handle the data but a cant change it. So what I need is to sort the data on the arrays in decreasing order first by the values on the x-coordinate and then the y-coordinate. And I'm not quite sure if I can use qsort for this. I'm NOT trying that someone solve this for me, but just direct me to some idea.

Comment: @netcoder: `qsort` would work well here if it were an array of structs (AoS), but the OP effectively has SoA...

Comment: @user20679 you don't actually ask specific question. This is not appreciated here. For your case: take any decent open source quick sort implementation (or some other algorithm). Then find a part where they swap elements. So in that place instead of swapping of original array, swap elements of other arrays with according index.

Comment: @Andrey: The question is *perfectly* clear; each of `x[i]`, `y[i]`, `w[i]`, and `z[i]` represent a record, and he wants to sort each record by `x` and `y`.  This would be dead easy if he had a struct to represent the four quantities, but he doesn't.

Comment: @JohnBode he can always compose array of such structures, sort, and break down into 4 arrays.

Comment: @user20679: If - as you said - you cannot change data layout. Use any fast sorting technique but whenever you'll have data swap in your code - swap data with same index in 4 arrays at the same time. This way in x[i],y[i],w[i],z[i] you'll have 'associated' values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *easy* way to do this would be to map your four separate arrays onto a single array of a struct type like

```
struct rec {
  double x;
  double y;
  double w;
  double z;
};

struct rec *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N ); // where N is the number of
                                             // elements in each array

if ( !arr )
  // malloc failed, handle error somehow

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  arr[i].x = x[i];
  arr[i].y = y[i];
  arr[i].w = w[i];
  arr[i].z = z[i];
}
```

and then create a comparison function to pass to `qsort`:

```
int cmpRec( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
  struct rec *l = lhs;
  struct rec *r = rhs;

  if ( l->x < r->x )
    return -1;
  else if ( l->x > r->x )
    return 1;
  else
  {
    if ( l->y < r->y )
      return -1;
    else if ( l->y > r->y )
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now you can use the `qsort` library function to sort that array of struct:

```
qsort( arr, N, sizeof *arr, cmpRec );
```

Once that array is sorted, you can map the results back onto your four original arrays.

Comment: OP said : I'm aware that this is not the best approach to handle the data but a cant change it.

Comment: @Artur I'm sure it can temporarily be changed.

Comment: Would look nicer is comparing func had conditions looking this way:

  if ( l->x < r->x ) return -1;
  if ( l->x > r->x ) return  1;

  if ( l->y < r->y ) return -1;
  if ( l->y > r->y ) return  1;

  return 0;

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) with

```
typedef struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double w;
    double z;
} Point;
```

Use qsort with

```
 typedef struct UglyThing {
   double x;
   int i;
 } UglyThing;
```

Create an array of size n, fill x with x values, i with index.
Call qsort. At the end, i will store the permutation order.
Swap the three other arrays according to the permutation order.
Then do the same with little arrays ("with same x") in the y direction.

If this ugly trick is not possible, then I don't see any other solution than reinventing the wheel.

(edit : I have just seen Andrew said something very close to this answer...sorry!)
Bye,

Francis

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, sorting this using standard `qsort()` is not going to work; there isn't a mechanism for passing four arrays.

Equally clearly, if the data were structured as an array of structures, then using `qsort()` would be feasible.

Question 1: Is it feasible to create an array of structures, load it, sort it, and then unload back into the original arrays?

Question 2: Another option is to sort an array of integers:

```
int indexes[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    indexes[i] = i;

qsort(indexes, n, sizeof(indexes[0]), comparator);
```

The `comparator` function would have to be able to access the `x` and `y` arrays as file scope variables:

```
int comparator(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    int i1 = *(int *)v1;
    int i2 = *(int *)v2;
    extern double *x, *y;
    if (x[i1] > x[i2])
        return +1;
    else if (x[i1] < x[i2])
        return -1;
    else if (y[i1] > y[i2])
        return +1;
    else if (y[i1] < y[i2])
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

You'd then be able to access the arrays using `x[indexes[i]]` etc to access the `i`th element in sorted order.

Is that acceptable?

If that is not convenient either, then you will end up writing your own sort; it isn't horribly painful, but will require some care.

---

I spent some time adapting an existing sort test framework to this scenario.  The full code is quite large because it includes a lot of testing support code.  The core function (compare, swap, partition and quicksort) are here (122 lines, including comment and blank lines):

```
/* SO 20271977 - sort arrays x, y, z, w (type double, size n) in parallel based on values in x and y */

/*
** To apply this to the real code, where there are 4 arrays to be sorted
** in parallel, you might write:
**
**    Array4 a;
**    a.x = x;
**    a.y = y;
**    a.z = z;
**    a.w = w;
**    a.n = n;
**    quicksort_random(&a);
**
** Or even:
**
**    quicksort_random((Array4){ .n = n, .x = x, .y = y, .z = z, .w = w });
**
** combining designated initializers and compound literals.  Or you could write a
** trivial wrapper so that you can call:
**
**    quicksort_random_wrapper(n, x, y, z, w);
*/

/* SOF so-20271977.h */
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct Array4
{
    size_t  n;
    double *x;
    double *y;
    double *z;
    double *w;
} Array4;

extern void quicksort_random(Array4 *A);
/* EOF so-20271977.h */

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* lrand48() */

/*
** Note that a more careful implementation would use nrand48() instead
** of lrand48() to prevent its random number generation from interfering
** with other uses of the x-rand48() functions.
*/

typedef size_t (*Part)(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r);

static void quicksort_partition(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r, Part partition);
static size_t partition_random(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r);

/* Quick Sort Wrapper function - specifying random partitioning */
void quicksort_random(Array4 *A)
{
    quicksort_partition(A, 0, A->n - 1, partition_random);
}

/* Main Quick Sort function */
static void quicksort_partition(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r, Part partition)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        size_t q = (*partition)(A, p, r);
        assert(p <= q && q <= r);
        if (q > 0)
            quicksort_partition(A, p, q-1, partition);
        quicksort_partition(A, q+1, r, partition);
    }
}

static inline int compare(Array4 const *A, size_t p, size_t r)
{
    if (A->x[p] < A->x[r])
        return -1;
    else if (A->x[p] > A->x[r])
        return +1;
    if (A->y[p] < A->y[r])
        return -1;
    else if (A->y[p] > A->y[r])
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static inline size_t random_int(size_t p, size_t r)
{
    return(lrand48() % (r - p + 1) + p);
}

static inline void swap(Array4 *A, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    double d;
    d = A->x[i];
    A->x[i] = A->x[j];
    A->x[j] = d;
    d = A->y[i];
    A->y[i] = A->y[j];
    A->y[j] = d;
    d = A->z[i];
    A->z[i] = A->z[j];
    A->z[j] = d;
    d = A->w[i];
    A->w[i] = A->w[j];
    A->w[j] = d;
}

static size_t partition_random(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r)
{
    size_t pivot = random_int(p, r);
    swap(A, pivot, r);
    size_t i = p-1;
    size_t j = p;

    while (j <= r)
    {
        if (compare(A, j, r) <= 0)
            swap(A, j, ++i);
        j++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

The test framework (quite ridiculously elaborate if it weren't that I already had a variant of it on hand) is 369 lines including blank lines and comment lines — and all the code above:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FLTFMT "%13.6f"

typedef struct Array4
{
    size_t  n;
    double *x;
    double *y;
    double *z;
    double *w;
} Array4;

static int trace = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *space = malloc(size);
    if (space == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory (%zu)\n", size);
        exit(1);
    }
    return space;
}

void quicksort_last(Array4 *A);
void quicksort_random(Array4 *A);
void selectionsort(Array4 *A);

static inline int compare(Array4 const *A, size_t p, size_t r)
{
    if (A->x[p] < A->x[r])
        return -1;
    else if (A->x[p] > A->x[r])
        return +1;
    if (A->y[p] < A->y[r])
        return -1;
    else if (A->y[p] > A->y[r])
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static void dump_array(char const *tag, Array4 const *A)
{
    printf("%s [%zu..%zu]:\n", tag, (size_t)0, A->n-1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A->n; i++)
        printf("(" FLTFMT ", " FLTFMT ", " FLTFMT ", " FLTFMT ")\n",
               A->x[i], A->y[i], A->z[i], A->w[i]);
}

static void chk_sort(Array4 const *A)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A->n - 1; i++)
    {
        //if (compare(A, i, i+1) > 0)
        {
            if (A->x[i] > A->x[i+1])
            {
                printf("Out of order: A.x[%zu] = " FLTFMT ", A.x[%zu] = " FLTFMT "\n",
                        i, A->x[i], i+1, A->x[i+1]);
            }
            else if ((A->x[i] == A->x[i+1] && A->y[i] > A->y[i+1]))
            {
                printf("Out of order: A.x[%zu] = " FLTFMT ", A.x[%zu] = " FLTFMT ", "
                        "A.y[%zu] = " FLTFMT ", A.y[%zu] = " FLTFMT "\n",
                        i, A->x[i], i+1, A->x[i+1], i, A->y[i], i+1, A->y[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

static inline void set(Array4 *A, size_t p, double d)
{
    A->x[p] = d;
    A->y[p] = d + drand48() - 0.5;
    A->z[p] = d / 2.0;
    A->w[p] = d * 2.0;
}

static void load_random(Array4 *A)
{
    size_t size = A->n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        A->x[i] = drand48() * size;
        A->y[i] = drand48() * size + drand48() - 0.5;
        A->z[i] = drand48() * size / 2.0;
        A->w[i] = drand48() * size * 2.0;
    }
}

static void load_ascending(Array4 *A)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A->n; i++)
        set(A, i, i);
}

static void load_descending(Array4 *A)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A->n; i++)
        set(A, i, A->n - i);
}

static void load_uniform(Array4 *A)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A->n; i++)
        set(A, i, A->n);
}

static void load_organpipe(Array4 *A)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= A->n / 2; i++)
        set(A, i, i);
    for (size_t i = A->n / 2 + 1; i < A->n; i++)
        set(A, i, A->n - i);
}

static void load_invorganpipe(Array4 *A)
{
    size_t range = A->n / 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < A->n / 2; i++)
        set(A, i, range - i);
    for (size_t i = A->n / 2 + 1; i < A->n; i++)
        set(A, i, i - range);
}

typedef void (*Load)(Array4 *A);
typedef void (*Sort)(Array4 *A);
typedef size_t (*Part)(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r);

static void test_one_sort(Array4 *A, Sort sort, char const *s_tag,
                          char const *l_tag, char const *z_tag)
{
    if (trace)
    {
        printf("%s-%s-%s:", z_tag, l_tag, s_tag);
        dump_array("Before", A);
    }
    clock_t start = clock();
    (*sort)(A);
    clock_t finish = clock();
    double sec = (finish - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%s-%s-%s: %13.6f\n", z_tag, l_tag, s_tag, sec);
    chk_sort(A);
    if (trace)
    {
        printf("%s-%s-%s:", z_tag, l_tag, s_tag);
        dump_array("After", A);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

static Array4 *alloc_array(size_t size)
{
    Array4 *A = xmalloc(sizeof(*A));
    A->n = size;
    A->x = xmalloc(size * sizeof(A->x[0]));
    A->y = xmalloc(size * sizeof(A->y[0]));
    A->z = xmalloc(size * sizeof(A->z[0]));
    A->w = xmalloc(size * sizeof(A->w[0]));
    return A;
}

static Array4 *dup_array(Array4 *A)
{
    size_t size = A->n;
    Array4 *B = alloc_array(size);
    if (B != 0)
    {
        B->n = size;
        memmove(B->x, A->x, size * sizeof(A->x[0]));
        memmove(B->y, A->y, size * sizeof(A->y[0]));
        memmove(B->z, A->z, size * sizeof(A->z[0]));
        memmove(B->w, A->w, size * sizeof(A->w[0]));
    }
    return B;
}

static void free_array(Array4 *A)
{
    free(A->x);
    free(A->y);
    free(A->z);
    free(A->w);
    free(A);
}

static void test_set_sorts(Array4 *A, char const *l_tag, char const *z_tag)
{
    struct sorter
    {
        Sort function;
        char const *tag;
    } sort[] =
    {
        { quicksort_last, "QS.L" },
        { quicksort_random, "QS.R" },
        { selectionsort, "SS.N" },
    };
    enum { NUM_SORTS = sizeof(sort) / sizeof(sort[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SORTS; i++)
    {
        Array4 *B = dup_array(A);
        test_one_sort(B, sort[i].function, sort[i].tag, l_tag, z_tag);
        free(B);
    }
}

static void test_set_loads(size_t size, char const *z_tag)
{
    struct loader
    {
        Load function;
        char const *tag;
    } load[] =
    {
        { load_random, "R" },
        { load_ascending, "A" },
        { load_descending, "D" },
        { load_organpipe, "O" },
        { load_invorganpipe, "I" },
        { load_uniform, "U" },
    };
    enum { NUM_LOADS = sizeof(load) / sizeof(load[0]) };
    Array4 *A = alloc_array(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOADS; i++)
    {
        load[i].function(A);
        test_set_sorts(A, load[i].tag, z_tag);
    }
    free_array(A);
}

/* Main Quick Sort function */
static void quicksort_partition(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r, Part partition)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        size_t q = (*partition)(A, p, r);
        assert(p <= q && q <= r);
        if (q > 0)
            quicksort_partition(A, p, q-1, partition);
        quicksort_partition(A, q+1, r, partition);
    }
}

static size_t partition_random(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r);
static size_t partition_last(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r);

/* Quick Sort Wrapper function - specifying random partitioning */
void quicksort_random(Array4 *A)
{
    quicksort_partition(A, 0, A->n - 1, partition_random);
}

/* Quick Sort Wrapper function - specifying partitioning about last element */
void quicksort_last(Array4 *A)
{
    quicksort_partition(A, 0, A->n - 1, partition_last);
}

static inline size_t random_int(size_t p, size_t r)
{
    return(lrand48() % (r - p + 1) + p);
}

static inline void swap(Array4 *A, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    double d;
    d = A->x[i];
    A->x[i] = A->x[j];
    A->x[j] = d;
    d = A->y[i];
    A->y[i] = A->y[j];
    A->y[j] = d;
    d = A->z[i];
    A->z[i] = A->z[j];
    A->z[j] = d;
    d = A->w[i];
    A->w[i] = A->w[j];
    A->w[j] = d;
}

static size_t partition_random(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r)
{
    size_t pivot = random_int(p, r);
    swap(A, pivot, r);
    size_t i = p-1;
    size_t j = p;

    while (j <= r)
    {
        if (compare(A, j, r) <= 0)
            swap(A, j, ++i);
        j++;
    }
    return i;
}

static size_t partition_last(Array4 *A, size_t p, size_t r)
{
    size_t i = p-1;
    size_t j = p;

    while (j <= r)
    {
        if (compare(A, j, r) <= 0)
            swap(A, j, ++i);
        j++;
    }
    return i;
}

/* Selection Sort algorithm */
void selectionsort(Array4 *A)
{
    size_t r = A->n;
    for (size_t p = 0; p < r; p++)
    {
        for (size_t i = p; i < r; i++)
        {
            if (compare(A, p, i) > 0)
                swap(A, p, i);
        }
    }
}

/*
** To apply this to the real code, where there are 4 arrays to be sorted
** in parallel, you might write:
**
**    Array4 a;
**    a.x = x;
**    a.y = y;
**    a.z = z;
**    a.w = w;
**    a.n = n;
**    quicksort_random(&a);
**
** Or even:
**
**    quicksort_random((Array4){ .n = n, .x = x, .y = y, .z = z, .w = w });
**
** combining designated initializers and compound literals.  Or you could write a
** trivial wrapper so that you can call:
**
**    quicksort_random_wrapper(n, x, y, z, w);
*/

int main(void)
{
    srand48((long)time(0));

    for (size_t i = 10; i <= 40; i += 10)
    {
        char buffer[10];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%zuK", i);
        test_set_loads(1000*i, buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```